# Bootstrapping allows retraining across the different bootstrapped datasets?

Tags: neural-networks, bootstrap, resampling

I am training a model and I would use bootstrapping since my dataset is really really small. Hence, I bootstrap a dataset, I train on it and then I get some validation error and metrics on the unseen part during the bootstrap instance: for every bootstrapped training instance there is some data that hasn't been sampled and I measure metrics on this part.
Once I pass to the next bootsrapped dataset, am I allowed for retraining the same model trained at the step before?
Both the training dataset and the validation one (the sampled and bootstrapped ones I am referring to) are augmented separately with noise, rotations etc (I am working with images, so I both augment training set and perform adversarial validation on test set).

At the end, I would like to get confidence intervals of the metrics computed during the bootstrapping over the unseen validation set.